# Size of database a factor for Hibernate vs JDBC?

Tags: database, sql, hibernate, jdbc

Do you know if the size of the database (number of tables used) is a factor when choosing between Hibernate and JDBC?

Why or why not?

In my particular case, I am evaluating Hibernate and JDBC for interacting with Oracle database for a small web app.

Comment: The number of tables generally does not (directly) matter.

Comment: When you say JDBC is better when Performance is critical, that is , result sets is large - what is the definition of large here ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The size in tables is by no means a concern when having to choose between the technologies. How could that possibly affect your choice? When you can map and generate your entities automatically, it doesn't even require you to write more boilerplate code when choosing an ORM.

It's rather a question about the tradeoff between programming close to the database and having an abstraction, although both can be mixed.

In general, sometimes it's better to program close to the database, for example when there're performance-critical tasks to fulfill. This can be done with Hibernate mostly, too. Sometimes it's just too memory-intensive to fetch whole entities or generated queries run too slow and you need custom SQL. Then you could use JDBC for it, although Hibernate can query the database using native SQL, too.

There're only a few cases in which I'd choose JDBC over Hibernate, as the abstraction of an ORM greatly benefits a clean programming model. For example if I was dealing with a legacy database that heavily relies on stored procedures which can't really be mapped to entities. Then it's probably better to not have the abstraction layer at all and just use a result-set oriented technology, like plain JDBC. Another point for choosing JDBC over Hibernate is when you are programming close to the relational paradigm. Objects/Entities could just be in the way of such applications. Anything that is very result-set oriented could probably be easier implemented by just using JDBC.

**Conclusion**

JDBC is better when:

- **Performance is critical** (result sets are large, which is a killer for many ORMs, queries need to be fine tuned for the specific RDBMS)
- You're dealing with **legacy databases/applications**, which were **coded in a heavily result-set oriented way**.

**However, nearly all other cases are better covered with an ORM like Hibernate, as in modern object oriented languages the benefit of code clarity outweighs other constraints.**

Answer (score 0):

From working with Hibernate over the years, one thing I would add about [Hibernate vs JDBC](https://www.theserverside.com/video/Hibernate-vs-JDBC-How-do-these-database-APIs-differ) is that with big databases, developers tend to make too many mappings, mapping every table in existence when their application only interacts with a small number of them. On it's own, that's not a huge problem. But, when Hibernate gets misused, such practices can bring an application to a stand-still.

**Hibernate and big database**

One of the big problems with Hibernate is getting access to data after a transaction is closed. If data hasn't been read eagerly, a null pointer occurs. It happens constantly during development.

Of course, there's an easy fix. Just eagerly load data from peripheral tables. It's fixes the problem, but it's seriously inefficient. And as more and more associated tables get eagerly loaded, the application gets slower and slower.

So, on its own, the database size isn't an issue. But if Hibernate is misused, you can run into serious performance problems. All the more reason to have a good data architect on hand and developers that really understand how to use [Hibernate and JPA](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Set-the-record-straight-on-the-JPA-and-Hibernate-debate).

**Bad JDCB programming**

In fairness, a developer using [JDBC or ODBC](https://www.theserverside.com/video/JDBC-vs-ODBC-Whats-the-difference-between-these-APIs) can write equally bad SQL that can ruin performance too. But it does tend to be easier to identify the problem when it happens.